# строка подключения mysql ado.net

Tags: c#, mysql, ado.net

1. поставил локально сервер mysql, сделал там схему с табличкой
2. скачал и подключил mysqlconnector (поскольку в ado его нет из коробки)
3. теперь нужно сформировать строку подключения, что бы соединить моё app и сервер

вот тут и возникли проблемы, пробовал делать вот так:

```
  var sc = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder()
        {
            Server = "127.0.0.1",
            Database = "usersdb",
            UserID = "root",
            Password = "root",
            SslMode = MySqlSslMode.None
        };
```

тогда всё хорошо работало

однако переделав это в единую строку:

```
var stringConnection = @"Server:127.0.0.1; Database:usersdb; User Id:root; Password:root; SslMode:0";
```

ничего не выходит и пишет: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

подскажите, как правильно сформировать строку подключения ^_^

Comment: моя строка выглядит так `"server=localhost; database=mydb; port=3306; user=root;"`. В смысле ваши двоеточия замените на знак равенства

Comment: Да, вы правы, теперь всё работает ^_^
оформите ваш комент, как ответ :)

Comment: готово, оформил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените двоеточия на знак равенства и все будет хорошо.